# Add a new line / line break to a multi line field using workflow string builder in SharePoint Designer

Tags: 2010, workflow, designer

From SharePoint Designer 2010, how can I add a new line or line break using the String Builder. I tried `<br />` and that didn't work. I tried put the new lines right in the string builder and that didn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
<![CDATA[<br/>]]> instead of <br />
```

Comment: Will try that right after I figure out this other issue. Workflows are great if you can get them to do what you want. :)

Comment: let me know if you need help with the other issue

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/178811/get-comment-feedback-from-start-feedback-process-workflow-in-spd-2010 if you have any ideas...

Comment: That did not work. It just added `<![CDATA[<br/>]]>` to the field.

Answer (score 0):

Strange... 
Pressing "Enter" at the end of the line or adding

```
<br/>
```

Should work to add new line in string builder.

Also check the type of your column. If your column is "Plain text" and this is not working for you, try using the "Enhanced Rich text" multiline text field.
You can add new question for your another issue.

Comment: does this answers your question?