# get comment/feedback from "Start Feedback Process" workflow in SPD 2010

Tags: 2010, workflow, tasks, designer, workflow-tasks-list

I have added a "Start Feedback Process" workflow to a list. The workflow works fine. The target user gets an email, they can click on it in Outlook, add their comments, and submit.

Now I am trying to figure out how to get the comments the user provided back in the next step of the workflow?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get save the comments field into a variable like this (screen shot from a task process WF though)

[image]

Comment: But how would I get the comments associated with the workflow/list that has the "Start Feedback Process" workflow?